# Add autoplay to jQuery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

Currently I have four pages that are full-width landing pages. I would like to add funcionality that will enable auto play. This will change the functionality to be more like a slideshow and less like static landing pages.

My current navigation for my landing pages has a " current navigation item selector;" here is my code for my current navigation that I'd like to add a jquery autoplay feature to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /** nav selector **/
    var bodyid = $('body').attr('id');   
    $('nav a.'+ bodyid).addClass('active');
    $("body").css("display", "none");

    $("body").fadeIn(500);

    $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);     
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML for the Nav:

Here is my CSS:
    nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:4%;
    left:10.45%;
    }
    nav a {
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0 7px;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: .85;
    border-radius: 999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 150ms;
    }
    nav a:hover, nav a.active{
    opacity:1;
    background:#007cc0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you might consider using a iframe to wrap the landing pages so that some transport controls or navigation can remain constant for the user. Your current arrangement sounds like it might be confusing, but I don't know the purpose so...

I would suggest that you statically define the next page in the HTML of each landing page, then use setTimeout() to navigate to that location after a period of time.

A more sophisticated implementation would include a way to stop the autoplay.

```
var nextPage = "http://your_domain.com/landing_page_2.html"; // set in each page.
var autoPlayEnabled = true; // toggle this with a play/pause button of some kind.

function navToNext()
{
   if(autoPlayEnabled)
   {
       $("body").fadeOut(500, function(){ window.location = nextPage; });           
   }
}

setTimeout(navToNext, 5000); // five seconds
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Taylor. I decided to use a plug-in with the auto start script.